# Ubuntu 20 GUI Reverted to older version

Tags: gui

Early to day my computer froze, and I force restarted it. Following the restart my GUI completely changed to an ancient looking interface. There's no side bar, all windows look they are from 2010 , and the background changed.

Not sure If I deleted something important or the everything just went wonky. Attached is the image of my desktop with the icons cropped out. Prior to this my desktop was basically just the default ubuntu 20 desktop.

[weird Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmKXd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your system; Ubuntu Core 20 is a *headless* system only, with the desktop only available with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu 20.10 (*which is EOL and has been awhile now*). Your provided image also looks more like an Xubuntu/Xfce system to be, over Ubuntu Desktop which uses GNOME   (*It's possible you've added another desktop (ie. Xfce/Xubuntu) making your system a multi-desktop system & have selected a Xfce session - but 20 is a server system only unlike 20.04 which allows desktops*). If you're using 20.04 (not 20), logout & selecting a different session will get you back to GNOME.

Comment: Switch to the Ubuntu / GNOME environment during login https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-and-switch-desktop-environments-in-ubuntu/